# how to solve this problme == Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'frm_proc' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, exception, multithreading

i have a from On this form i have a button...
on the click event write this code

> ```
> _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new MethodInvoker(() =>
>             {
>
>                 progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => progressBar1.Visible = true));
>                 Print formp = new Print();
>                 formp.ShowDialog();
>                 this.Hide();
>
>
>             }));
> ```

but i recived error on  this.Hide()  ...
how can i solve

Answer (score 1):

You can´t access controls from a thread other than the GUI thread, you´ll need to use [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) to check if such is the case. If so, you'll need to invoke your call on the GUI thread.

It's hard to tell without the context, but maybe you should ask yourself if you need to run this code asynchronously.

Comment: In this case he *knows* he is not on the GUI thread (he is in a BackgroundWorker).  No need to perform the check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.Invoke(new System.Action(()=>this.Hide()));
```

You are not allowed to access UI controls (or their parent form) from a thread other than the one running that form's message pump (commonly referred to as it's UI thread).  In this case, `this` refers to the form itself.

Comment: thanks chris but this show error : Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Thanks Chris i Resolve it  By :> this.Invoke((Action)delegate { this.Hide(); });